# ERROR: Encountered error during push registration with OneSignal: Error Domain=OneSignalError Code=400 "

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, push-notification, onesignal

It have been a white I'm facing a issue while integrating one-signal to my app for iOS 
i followed every thing in the ionic guide and one-signal 
but getting this error

> ERROR: Encountered error during push registration with OneSignal:
>   Error Domain=OneSignalError Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={returned={
>       errors =     (
>           "app_id not found. You may be missing a Content-Type: application/json header."
>       ); }}

I'm sure the `app_id` is correct

any body help this is my code :

```
platform.ready().then(() => {


  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();

if(platform.is('ios')){
    console.log('platform is ios using onsignail for ios');
    this.oneSignal.startInit('bae0c3e1-bc4e-49ab-9274-18635XXXXX', );

this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.InAppAlert);

this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(() => {
    // do something when notification is received
});

this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(() => {
    // do something when a notification is opened
});

this.oneSignal.endInit();
```

}

this is the output in xcode console

> ERROR: Encountered error during push registration with OneSignal: Error Domain=OneSignalError Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={returned={
>       errors =     (
>           "app_id not found. You may be missing a Content-Type: application/json header."
>       );
>   }}
>   2018-09-20 09:48:39.056130+0100 Baby Fashion[514:115983] ERROR: Encountered error during email registration with OneSignal: (null)

thank you for your help

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start OneSignal as soon as possible, else it will not provide app_id while app trying to hook plugin with ios and it will throw error.

And you have code inside `platform.ready` method so oneSignal taking time to initialize while plugin trying to hook.

You also need to set firebase project id to enable push notification for Android app.